# What's wrong with my Lychrel number finder?

Tags: python, lychrel-numbers

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler problem #55](http://projecteuler.net/problem=55), which states:

> If we take 47, reverse and add, 47 + 74 = 121, which is palindromic.
>
> Not all numbers produce palindromes so quickly. For example,
>
> 349 + 943 = 1292, 1292 + 2921 = 4213, 4213 + 3124 = 7337
>
> That is, 349 took three iterations to arrive at a palindrome.
>
> Although no one has proved it yet, it is thought that some numbers,
>   like 196, never produce a palindrome. A number that never forms a
>   palindrome through the reverse and add process is called a Lychrel
>   number. Due to the theoretical nature of these numbers, and for the
>   purpose of this problem, we shall assume that a number is Lychrel
>   until proven otherwise. In addition you are given that for every
>   number below ten-thousand, it will either (i) become a palindrome in
>   less than fifty iterations, or, (ii) no one, with all the computing
>   power that exists, has managed so far to map it to a palindrome. In
>   fact, 10677 is the first number to be shown to require over fifty
>   iterations before producing a palindrome: 4668731596684224866951378664
>   (53 iterations, 28-digits).
>
> Surprisingly, there are palindromic numbers that are themselves
>   Lychrel numbers; the first example is 4994.
>
> How many Lychrel numbers are there below ten-thousand?

**TL;DR:** If a number is not a palindrome, add it to the reverse of itself. Still no? Repeat. *...50 iterations later...* It's a Lychrel number.

My code:

```
def isPalindrome(n):
    return str(n)[::-1] == str(n)

lychrels = 0

for i in range(1,10000):
    lychrel = True
    for j in range(50):
        if isPalindrome(i):
            lychrel = False
            break

        else:
            i += int(str(i)[::-1])

    if lychrel:
        lychrels += 1

print(lychrels)
```

It works correctly for the test cases of 349 (non-Lychrel) and 196 (Lychrel), but Project Euler is rejecting the answers I'm getting.

I **have not** yet solved the problem, so I would prefer **hints** over a direct solution.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first number that your function fails for is `4994`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make an incorrect assumption about a number that starts off as a palindrome not being lychrel. I think that's your only error.